# Condition to stop Android Chronometer

Tags: android, chronometer

I am trying to stop my android chronometer when it gets to 10 seconds but I can't seem to get it work.
My code is as below for anyone to point me out in the right direction.
Thank you.

```
if(chronorun == false){
         chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
         chronometer.start();
         chronorun = true;
         Vibrator vib = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vib.vibrate(100);
        elapsedTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        if(elapsedTime == 10)
        {chronometer.stop();}
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a `Runnable` that stops your `Chronometer`, and use the `postDelayed()` method to have it run in 10 seconds:

```
Runnable stopClock = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        chronometer.stop();
        Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vib.vibrate(100);
    }               
};

chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
chronometer.start();
chronometer.postDelayed(stopClock, 1000 * 10);
```

NB: the second parameter in `postDelayed()` is the delay in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Use Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() here is the code

```
final Chronometer myChronometer = (Chronometer) getActivity().findViewById(
        R.id.chronometer1);

myChronometer.start();
myChronometer
        .setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
                if( chronometer.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("00:10"))
                    Toast.makeText(context,
                        "time reached", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     //HERE YOU CAN DO YOUR CODE
            }
        });
```